# Powerbuilder 12 .net tutorials

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I'm looking for beginners tutorials to build asp.net applications with Powerbuilder 12. if you know any resources, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find some tutorials here http://www.sybase.com/powerbuilder12/tutorials
Some video tutorials here http://programming-video-tutorial.blogspot.com/search/label/Power%20Builder
Another tutorial here http://www.devx.com/enterprise/Article/42651.
Don't forget to look in **PowerBuilderTV**. One of the best resources on web. See their webinar's archive http://www.powerbuilder.tv/index.php/en/archived-webinars/powerbuilder

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some more PowerBuilder 12 and PowerBuilder 12.NET Training Resources. These are all free, some may require a free registration on The Sybase Developer Network (SDN). This entire list (plus new items being added) can be found at the [DisplacedGuy PowerBuilder Blog](http://www.displacedguy.com/tech/powerbuilder-12-5-pb-net-free-training-and-tutorials/)

**Sample Applications and Code Examples**

- [CodeXchange](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1058501), allows developers to submit and download PB code samples.
- [PowerBuilder 12 .NET Stock Trader](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1069347) Reference Application

**PowerBuilder 12 Video Tutorials and Training for PowerBuilder .NET**

- [Video Demo: PowerBuilder .NET Guided Tour -- Part 1](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1069340)
- [Video Tutorial: WPF Benefits for PowerBuilder Developers](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1069344)
- [Video Tutorial: PowerBuilder WCF Client Support](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1069345)
- [Video Tutorial: Powerscript Language Enhancements](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1069346)
- [eTutorial: PowerBuilder 12 .NET StockTrader Sample Application](http://video.sybase.com/products/powerbuilder/StockTrader_ePresentation/index.html)
- [PowerScript .NET Tutorial](http://video.sybase.com/products/powerbuilder/powerscript-dot-net-tutorial/player.html) - Video Tutorial
- [PowerBuilder and WCF Tutorial](http://video.sybase.com/products/powerbuilder/wcf-tutorial/player.html) - Video Tutorial

**PowerBuilder 12 Migration eTutorial: Migrating PB Classic to PowerBuilder 12 .NET**

- [Part 1 Migration Overview and Process](http://video.sybase.com/products/powerbuilder/Part-1-Migrating-Classic-Applications-to-PowerBuilder-12-.NET/index.html)
- [Part 2 Platform and Language Issues](http://video.sybase.com/products/powerbuilder/Part-2-Migrating-Classic-Applications-to-PowerBuilder-12-.NET/index.html)
- [Part 3: Sample Application Tour: Anchor Bay Nut Company (ABNC)](http://video.sybase.com/products/powerbuilder/Part-3-Migrating-Classic-Applications-to-PowerBuilder-12-.NET/index.html)
- [Part 4: Migrating and Refactoring ABNC](http://video.sybase.com/products/powerbuilder/Part-4-Migrating-Classic-Applications-to-PowerBuilder-12-.NET/index.html)

**Presentations from Sybase Tech Days 2011** (you may need to register on Sybase website for these)

- [PB 12.5 Look-Ahead](http://www.sybase.com/files/Thankyou_Pages/PowerBuilder_12.5_A_Look_Ahead.pdf) - by John Strano & David Fish
- [Migrating to .Net](http://www.sybase.com/files/Thankyou_Pages/2011_Sybase_TechDays_-_Migrating_PowerBuilder_Applications_to_.NET.pdf) - By John Strano & David Fish
- [PowerBuilder Overview & Roadmap](http://www.sybase.com/files/Thankyou_Pages/RoadmapPowerBuilder.pdf) - By John Strano & David Fish

**PB Tech Corner - Links To**

- [PB Newsgroups](http://www.sybase.com/detail_list?id=78348)
- [Technical Whitepapers](http://www.sybase.com/detail_list?id=78350)
- [Tech Notes](http://www.sybase.com/detail_list?id=78351)
- [Product Manuals](http://www.sybase.com/detail_list?id=78352)
- [Product Manuals](http://www.sybase.com/detail_list?id=78352)

[Sybase International User Group](http://my.isug.com/p/cm/ld?fid=53) - Great place to learn, get free copies of PowerBuilder 11.5 & 12.NET